# Handle either a string or int in JSON response

Tags: ios, json, parsing, nsdictionary

If catData is a dictionary returned from a rest API call:

```
NSString* catId = catData[@"id"];
```

This is fine if catData[@"id"] is a string. Not so much if it's an int or something else.

I tried this:

```
NSString* catId = [catData[@"id"] stringValue];
```

But that results in this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa000030383130365'
```

How can I properly handle any type of value and get it converted to the string that I need?

I'm using AFNetworking with AFJSONResponseSerializer.

Answer (score 5):

instead of using

```
NSString* catId = [catData[@"id"] stringValue
```

both case use

```
NSString* catId = catData[@"id"];
```

crash happen because you are trying to convert **string** to **string** value